# Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. **M** было 0x7., С

Tags: c, массивы, ссылки

Программа считывает строку, а дальше проверяет чтобы в строке был корректно введен массив из вещественных чисел и возвращает значение в переменную M.

```
float mas[100]; //нужный массив чисел
char *M;//символьный массив в корректной форме
char arr[10000];
float *Q =mas;//==mas
if (choise == 1)
{
    gets_s(arr);
    M = ArrayCheck(arr);//проверяем массив на верность введенных данных
        if (M[0] != 'e')
        {
            Q = ArrToInt(arr);//переводим массив из символьного в числовой
            if (flag == false)
            {
                flag = true;
                return 0;
            }

        }
    }
Вот сама функция, проверяющая строку:


 char * ArrayCheck(char str[])
{
    char error[1] = { 'e' };
    for (int i=0; i < len(str); i++)
    {
        if ((str[i] >= '0') && (str[i] <= '9'))continue;
        else if (str[i] == '.' || str[i] == ' ')
        {
            if ((i >= 1) && (i < len(str) - 1))
            {
                if ((str[i - 1] >= '0') && (str[i - 1] <= '9') && (str[i + 1] >= '0') && (str[i + 1] <= '9'))continue;
                else return error;
            }
            else return error;
        }
        else if (str[i] == '-')
        {
            if ((i >= 1) && (i < len(str) - 1))
            {
                if (str[i - 1]== ' ' && (str[i + 1] >= '0') && (str[i + 1] <= '9'))continue;
                else return error;
            }
            else return error;
        }
        else return error;
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: `char error[1] = { 'e' };` возврат указателя на локальный массив. дальше не смотрел =)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: А зачем вообще такие мучения вместо `scanf`, грубо говоря?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `c` и `c++` массивы сами не копируются. Возвращая из функции массив, на самом деле вы возвращаете указатель на его первый элемент. При положительном результате, вы в указатель `M` присвоите адрес `arr[]`, т.е. они оба будут указывать на массив `arr[]`. А вот при отрицательном - вы вернете указатель на массив `char error[1]`, который был создан локально и при выходе из функции был уничтожен. Да и создание массива из 1 элемента - странный ход.

```
M = ArrayCheck(arr); 

char* ArrayCheck(char str[])
{
    char error[1] = { 'e' };
    if ()
       {}
    else 
       return error;  // при - возвращается указатель на локальный массив
    return str; // при + возвращается указатель на исходный массив
}
```

Поскольку вы просто проверяете строку на корректность, никуда не копируя данные, вам нужно в функцию передать указатель на массив, а вернуть результат проверки - положительный или отрицательный.

```
if( ArrayCheck(arr) )
   {} // строка корректна
else
   {}

bool ArrayCheck(char str[])
{
    if ()
       {}
    else 
       return false;
    return true;
```

Comment: чисто ради интереса. а откуда краш программы? Читать из более-менее своей области памяти _обычно_ не приводит к такому. или это особенности конкретного компилятора в конкретном дебаг режиме?

Comment: скорее всего чтение по указателю на несуществующий массив.